# Find the antiderivative of : $f\left( x \right) =x^{a}\left( bx^c+K\right) ^d$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to know the primitive function (Antiderivative) of this function:
$$f\left( x \right) =x^{a}\left( bx ^c+K\right) ^d$$
where

- $K$ is an integration constant,
- $d=-\frac{1}{2p}$ with $p<0$,
- $a=-c_{1}$ , $b=\frac{2pc_{2}}{2pc_{1}-1}$ , $c=1-2pc_{1}$ and the constants $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are:
  $$
  c_{1}=\left( \frac{1}{2n\left( 1-p\right) }+\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right) \quad  c_{2}=\frac{\alpha }{\left( 1-p\right) \left( 2n\right) ^{-2p+2}}\qquad n\in \mathbb{N}, \alpha<0
  $$

Please could you help me in finding how could I find the primitive of this function? Is there any particular technique concerning this types of functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The links in my comment to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415575/15780) might help.

Comment: Find the formula here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/416099/454 (not yet solved).

Comment: @GEdgar. I am sorry ! I did not "see" your comment and the work you have done in the linked question.  Do you prefer I delete my answer ? No problem for me. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int x^{a}\left( b\,x ^c+k\right) ^d \,dx$$
Let
$$ \frac{b x^c}{k}=t\implies x=\left(\frac{k t}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{c}}\implies dx=\frac{k }{b c }\left(\frac{k t}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{c}-1}\,dt$$ Replace and simplify to get
$$I=\frac 1c b^{-\frac{a+2 c-1}{c}} k^{\frac{a+1}{c}+d}\int (t+1)^d\, t^{\frac{a+1}{c}-1}\,dt$$

As @Aaron Hendrickson commented

$$\int (t+1)^d\, t^{\frac{a+1}{c}-1}\,dt=\frac{c }{a+1}\,t^{\frac{a+1}{c}}\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{a+1}{c},-d;\frac{a+c+1}{c};-t\right)$$

Back to $x$
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac{ k^d }{a+1}\,x^{a+1}\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{a+1}{c},-d;\frac{a+c+1}{c};-\frac{b
   }{k}x^c\right)}$$

Comment: Dear, do you have a reference (book, paper, url, etc.) for the integral identity involving the hypergeometric function? Where does that identity come from? Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo. This is almost the definition of the gaussian hypergeometric function. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function  $$\int (t+1)^{\alpha } t^{\beta }\,dt=\frac{t^{\beta +1} }{\beta +1}\,\, _2F_1(-\alpha ,\beta +1;\beta +2;-t)$$

Comment: Dear, I looked at the url you sent me, but I couldn't find such definition.

Answer (score 1):

The [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) may be a way, however messy, to progress. (I can't think of a "nice" answer that won't involve an infinite series at the moment.)

We have

$$(1-x)^{-s} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{s+k-1}{k} x^k$$

wherein we adopt the definition

$$\binom{\alpha}{k} := \frac{\alpha (\alpha -1)(\alpha -2) \cdots (\alpha - (k-1))}{k!}$$

These work even for $\alpha,s$ not positive integers, and coincide with the usual definitions and results for positive integers, hence it being a generalization.

---

Then note that

$$(bx^c+K)^d = K^d \left( 1 - \left( -\frac{b}{K}  x^c \right)\right)^{-1/2p}$$

and then by the expansion,

$$(bx^c+K)^d
= K^d \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k-1+1/2p}{k} \frac{(-1)^k b^k}{K^k} x^{ck} $$

For simplicity define now the constants

$$\beta_k :=  \binom{k-1+1/2p}{k} \frac{(-1)^k b^k}{K^k}$$

ensuring the simpler expression

$$(bx^c+K)^d =  K^d \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k x^{ck}$$

and

$$f(x) = K^d \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k x^{ck+a}$$

Integration of this, assuming the ability to interchange infinite summation and integral may be justified, is trivial enough.

Comment: It looks like this should be able to be written in closed-form in terms of hypergeometric functions.